# How to extract text between single-line source code comment?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex to match source code comments:

```
private Pattern parser = Pattern.compile("^\\s*((?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|(?://.*))\\s*$");
```

This regex will match these types of comments:

```
// Comment
/* Comment */
/******** Comment ********/
```

It is very important that this regular expression matches also comments with indentation before and after the comment.

Now I want to create capturing groups so I can easily access the text inside the comment.

I tried to remove the non capturing groups but that didn't work as expected. How can I extend this regular expression in order to access the text inside the comment?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve but if your intent is to extract various structures in source code, consider https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to remove the comment notation and the text from the comment, these two regular expressions will identify comments, and their text, so that you can remove them.

```
\/\*([\S\s]+?)\*\/

(?s)/\*.*?\*/
```

*These two will remove 3 types of comment*

```
/**** Test ****/

/*
 *
 *  Here is another comment
 *
 *
 */

 /* Comment 




 */
```

*This regex will remove the following types of comment*

```
//.*$

your code //Comment Comment
```

**Example in NP++**

[image: Highlights full comment]

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your regular expression grouping works perfectly for this type of comment: `/* Comment */`. Is it possible to extend the regular expression in order to make it also work with `// Comment` and `/******* Comment *******/`?

Comment: @JohnDoe Edited answer to show regexes which will remove all types of comment

Comment: @JohnDoe If this works for you please could you accept it as an answer using the tick. I would appreciate it.